How can I use PHP's NumberFormatter with `PADDING_POSITION` and `CURRENCY`?
I'm attempting to achieve the same thing I can achieve in javascript like so:
Intl.NumberFormat('en-CA', {style: 'currency', currency: 'CAD', notation: 'compact', maximumSignificantDigits: 5 }).format(12345000000);
// Output: $12.345B"
Intl.NumberFormat('fr-CA', {style: 'currency', currency: 'CAD', notation: 'compact', maximumSignificantDigits: 5 }).format(12345000000);
// Output: "12,345 G$"

I can do the shortform notation like so:
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en_CA', NumberFormatter::PADDING_POSITION);
$formatter->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::SIGNIFICANT_DIGITS_USED, 5);
echo $formatter->format(12345000000);

// Output: 12.345B

$formatter = new NumberFormatter('fr_CA', NumberFormatter::PADDING_POSITION);
$formatter->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::SIGNIFICANT_DIGITS_USED, 5);
echo $formatter->format(12345000000);

// Output: 12,345 G

Or I can do currency formatting like this:
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en_CA', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo $formatter->formatCurrency(12345000000, 'CAD');

// Output: $12,345,000,000.00

$formatter = new NumberFormatter('fr_CA', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo $formatter->formatCurrency(12345000000, 'CAD');

// Output: 12 345 000 000,00 $

But I can't combine the two. If I attempt it like so, the $ does not display:
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en_CA', NumberFormatter::PADDING_POSITION);
$formatter->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::SIGNIFICANT_DIGITS_USED, 5);
echo $formatter->formatCurrency(12345000000, 'CAD');

// Output: 12.345B

$formatter = new NumberFormatter('fr_CA', NumberFormatter::PADDING_POSITION);
$formatter->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::SIGNIFICANT_DIGITS_USED, 5);
echo $formatter->formatCurrency(12345000000, 'CAD');

// Output: 12,345 G

The php.net documentation for NumberFormatter is surprisingly sparse. Is what I'm trying to do impossible or is there some other trick here?
I know I can roll a custom solution here but I would like to be able to rely on built-in l18n methods like I can in JavaScript.

The second argument to the NumberFormatter is a style constant, and NumberFormatter::PADDING_POSITION is an attribute identifier. I don't know what style constant that that attribute ID is equivalent to, but what you're asking is essentially to have the number styled according to two different styles simultaneously, which is not going to be possible.

The best you're going to be able to get is using getPattern() to get the style patterns, merge them yourself by hand, and then use setPattern() to create a custom formatter. See the ICU docs linked off this page.

If the JS code is based on ICU you can probably extract the patterns from there and use them directly as well.

I can't reproduce your "shortform notation" in PHP. It throws an error.

@Sammitch re: style identifiers vs attribute identifiers, I came across many examples of NumberFormatter::PADDING_POSITION used as a second argument that way when I was searching for how to do this, but was likewise confused when looking up the docs. It works to get the shorthand output though. The php docs leave me with a lot of questions about NumberFormatter

@Olivier, FWIW I'm running PHP8.1. I believe php-intl is a requirement here.

All those constants just map to numbers, so it's totally possible to mix them up with little consequence. But even stranger is that PADDING_POSITION is 14 and there is no defined style constant with that value, at least not in PHP. That value is leaking out into the underlying ICU library and mapping to a style constant that PHP has not named, eg: this. I would not recommend depending on this as the format that 14 points at may change without warning.

@dave It fails when executed on https://onlinephp.io/ but it seems to be caused by an old version of ICU. Anyway, this is an undocumented feature, so use it with care.

@Sammitch The solution I've settled on for now is to use NumberFormatter for the currency part and custom methods for the shorthand piece. But this seemingly undocumented behaviour (which I was pointed to by several other threads on StackOverflow) was the only way I found to get the shorthand notation to work. Can you find a documented way to do such shorthand?

This Github issue points to a similar confusion about this undocumented feature and links to other libraries where people are using it. Very strange: https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/3850 It's also the accepted answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66096887/convert-long-numbers-to-short-and-compact
